# check if a function exists with its name in a string?

Tags: javascript

I create functions in Javascript *dynamically*. Sometimes I need to check if a certain function is actually already created.

I have the name of the function as a string. How can I check whether a function exists based on a given value in a string?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can check whether it's defined in the global scope using;

```
if (typeof window[strOfFunction] === "function") {
    // celebrate
    //window[strOfFunction](); //To call the function dynamically!
}
```

Comment: How would this work for a jQuery plugin? like $.fn.mask?

Comment: What about if I want to allow my function to pass `window` in string format too?

`load.js("script.js", function() {}, "window.myCallbackFn");`

Comment: Doesn't work when you don't have a `window` object, like with node.

Comment: Can you use `this` instead of `window`? Will that work in node and a browser? Or would `if (typeof (window || this)[strOfFunction] === "function") { /* ... */ }` be better form?

Answer (score 8):

You can use eval:

```
if ( eval("typeof stringFunction === 'function'") ){ /*whatever*/ }
```

Comment: The use of `eval` should never be taken lightly. One needs to understand the implications of using it. See [Eval is Evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) and [Eval isn't evil, just misunderstood](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/).

Comment: You can use eval() for many things but you should really only use it if you have no other alternative. It is handy to be able to just slap a string together and get it to evaluate.

    if ( eval("typeof stringFunction === 'function'") ){ /*whatever*/ }

IMHO should be

    eval("answer = typeof stringFunction === 'function'");
    if ( answer ){ /*whatever*/ }

Some funny stuff is happening with things like with, eval, this, and some muppet theory regarding the use of "use strict"; to help improve coding, fine if you are going to make it a compiled language but JS isn't...

Comment: Literally always some guy has to point out that "eval is evil". Using eval is fine if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I love eval.
Eval is the angel

Answer (score 0):

We're adding our 2 cents because the accepted answer is right, but benefits from a little clarification:

`window["myFunctionNameHere"]` is one simple way to solve the problem, but basically considering `window` as any global object accessible in the desired scope.
Additionally, you must be sure to actually ASSIGN the function properly in such scope, of course.

In the case of window, for example, you'll first need

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.myFunctionNameHere = function() {
            console.log('Hello world');
        }
    });
</script>
```

After this, the

```
typeof window["myFunctionNameHere"] === "function"
```

Will work as expected.