# How to check if an angularjs controller has been defined

Tags: angularjs, config, controllers

I've got an app defined this way:

```
angular.module("myApp", [...])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $controllerProvider) {
    if (isControllerDefined(controllerName)) {
      do_stuff();
    }
  })
```

The controllers are defined this way:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .controller("myController", function ($scope) { ... });
```

How can I define `isControllerDefined()` (in the config above) to check whether a given controller exists if I have the name of the controller?  I feel like I should be able to do something like one of these:

```
var ctrl = angular.module("myApp").getController("myController");
var ctrl = $controllerProvider.get("myController");
```

or something like that... but I can't find any functionality for this.  Help?

Comment: Just curious what the need to check if a controller is registered is.

Comment: Sadly, I don't remember now (almost a year later).  I *think* I might have been doing a dev build of a project and wanted introspection to facilitate documentation.  I upvoted your comment because you didn't just assume it was invalid to want to do that (I hate that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example of a service that can check if a controller exists. Note that it looks for a [global function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8592069/878514) with specified name as well as a controller in the `$controller` provider.

```
angular.service('ControllerChecker', ['$controller', function($controller) {
  return {
    exists: function(controllerName) {
      if(typeof window[controllerName] == 'function') {
        return true;
      }
      try {
        $controller(controllerName);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return !(error instanceof TypeError);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/HB7LU/6780/) for usage.

Comment: Must one have the controller checker ***after*** the actual controller it is checking?

Comment: See the GlennFilson comment for the answer below. When the dependencies for the controller can not be provided, the TypeError is thrown. This may for example happen when you try to instantiate "normal" function as a controller.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this exact same issue the other day. I had a few issues with the currently accepted answer, namely because one of my controllers was performing an initialization call out to the server upon instantiation to populate some data (i.e):

```
function ExampleController($scope, ExampleService) {
    ExampleService.getData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.foo = data.foo;
        $scope.bar = data.bar
    });
}
```

As it stands, the currently accepted answer will actually instantiate the controller, before discarding it. This lead to multiple API calls being made on each request (one to verify that the controller exists, one to actually use the controller).

I had a bit of a dig around in the `$controller` [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js)  and found that there's an undocumented parameter you can pass in called `later` which will delay instantiation. It will, however, still run all of the checks to ensure that the controller exists, which is perfect!

```
angular.factory("util", [ "$controller", function($controller) {
    return {
        controllerExists: function(name) {
            try {
                // inject '$scope' as a dummy local variable
                // and flag the $controller with 'later' to delay instantiation
                $controller(name, { "$scope": {} }, true);
                return true;
            }
            catch(ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

UPDATE: Probably a lot easier as a decorator:

```
angular.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.delegate('$controller', [ '$delegate', function($delegate) {
        $delegate.exists = function(controllerName) {
            try {
                // inject '$scope' as a dummy local variable
                // and flag the $controller with 'later' to delay instantiation
                $delegate(controllerName, { '$scope': {} }, true);
                return true;
            }
            catch(ex) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```

Then you can simply inject `$controller` and call `exists(...)`

```
function($controller) {
    console.log($controller.exists('TestController') ? 'Exists' : 'Does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no easy way of fetching a list of controllers. That is hidden for internal use only. You would have to go to the source code and add a public method that return the internal controllers variable (in $ControllerProvider function)
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js#L16

```
this.getControllers = function() {
    return controllers;
    // This will return an object of all the currently defined controllers
  };
```

Then you can just do

```
app.config(function($controllerProvider) {
    var myCtrl = $controllerProvider.getControllers()['myController'];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since angular `1.5.1` *(not released yet at the time of writing)*, there is a new way to check whether a controller exists or not through the `$ControllerProvider.has('MyCtrlName')` method.

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13951

Github PR: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14109

Commit backported in 1.5.1 directly: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bb9575dbd3428176216355df7b2933d2a72783cd

---

*Disclaimer: Since many people were interested by this feature, I made a PR, because I also need it is some of my projects.* Have fun! :)

This PR has been based on @trekforever answer, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @Vadorequest, nice! anyone using that don' t forget $controllerProvider (lowerCase c )

Answer (score 2):

You could use the $controller service and do $controller('myController') and wrap a try-catch  arround it so you know if it fails.

Comment: This is not a great solution as there are any number of reasons that $controller might throw an exception.  For example, without knowing what special dependencies a controller may have, if those dependencies are not provided an exception will be thrown.

Comment: However you will still be able to tell what the specific exception is and decide what to do from there.