# Angular UI Router - how to handle invalid controller from controllerProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use [Angular UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and have defined the following state:

```
$stateProvider.state('objectDetails', {
  url: '/object/:type/:id',
  templateUrl: 'url/to/my/template.html',
  controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
    capitalized = $stateParams.type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $stateParams.type.substr(1)
    return capitalized + 'DetailsController'
  }
});
```

When I enter the `/object/flower/123` I expect the controller of the view to be `FlowerDetailsController` etc. It works.

Question is how to handle an error (invalid object type in an url). I.e. the `WeedDetailsController` does not exist and when I enter the `/object/weed/123`, [the error is being thrown](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=WeedDetailsController&p1=not%20aNaNunction,%20got%20undefined).

How the controller provider is supposed to notify UI router that it can not provide any controller for given params? I would expect the router to display `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` path, which I specified with nice 404 error.

Comment: What about [checking if the controller exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737880/1800245) - if not providing a controller where you handle this error?