# Unknown provider: $controller

Tags: angularjs

I can access $controllerProvider but can not access $controller in the following method

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME, ['common'])
    .config(['$routeProvider','$controllerProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {
        console.log($controllerProvider);//defined
        console.log($controller);//undefined
}]);
```

If I use $controller as dependency injection, it is giving

```
Unknown provider: $controller
```

But I need to access it, How do I do that

**EDIT**

I need this because I want to check my controller exists not not. Here is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734565/how-to-check-if-an-angularjs-controller-has-been-defined) where from I am using this code

```
try {
     $controller(controllerName);
     listControlerName = MODULE_NAME+'ListController';
} catch (error) {
     listControlerName = 'CommonListController';
}
```

**CONTEXT**

I am creating architecture of a project. My project structure as follows.

1. I have one COMMON module. with ListController, EditController, ViewController
2. I have some other modules like MOD1, MOD2 etc with MOD1ListController, MOD1EditController, MOD1ViewController so on.
3. Those module specific controller extend corresponding  controller from Common Module.

Now my plan is while a new module (MODX) need to be developed, then if there is some extra functionality, then only developer will create a new MODXListController for that module by inheriting common ListController. Otherwise they need not to create any thing.

So system will check if that module contains MODXListController or not. If not then system will use Common ListController.

I do not want to create a MODXListController which inherits common ListController but does not do any extra change. Because I have lots of module nearly 25 and all of then are sharing same functionality mostly.

Comment: you can't access `$controller` from your config.

Comment: Please, provide the context why exactly it is unknown if the controller exists. There are better ways to do what you're trying to do, certainly not like that.

Comment: @estus I have updated the context.

Comment: Extending from abstract parent with zero changes is common practice in OOP and shouldn't be avoided. Especially if the alternatives are nonviable (try-catch $controller is horrible but others are even worse). There's a bunch of good recipes for Angular controller inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicitly inheriting all controllers (which is acceptable but verbose solution), a good alternative is to wrap controller switching functionality into `mod-controller` directive (similar to `ng-controller`), something like that:

```
angular.module('common', [])
.constant('MODULE_NAME', 'Common')
.constant('modControllers', [])
.controller('CommonEditController', ...);
.controller('CommonListController', ...);
.directive('modController', function (MODULE_NAME, modControllers) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    priority: 500,
    controller: function ($controller, $attrs, $scope) {
      var ctrlName = (modControllers.indexOf($attrs.modController) >=0 ? MODULE_NAME : 'Common') + $attrs.modController;

      angular.extend(this, $controller(ctrlName, { $scope: $scope }));
    });
  };
});

angular.module('mod1', ['common'])
.constant('MODULE_NAME', 'Mod1')
.constant('modControllers', ['ListController']);
.controller('Mod1ListController', function ($controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('CommonListController');
  ...
});
```

When the controller should be specified in application code rather than view (i.e. route and directive controllers), the similar thing can be done with controller factory.

```
angular.module('common')
.provider('ctrlFactory', function (MODULE_NAME, modControllers) {
  function factoryFn(ctrlName) {
    return (modControllers.indexOf(ctrlName) >=0 ? MODULE_NAME : 'Common') + ctrlName;
  };

  this.get = this.$get = factoryFn;
});
```

It can be injected into directives and used as

```
...
controller: ctrlFactory('ListController')
```

Due to the fact that it returns controller name instead of `$controller` instance and depends only on constant services (MODULE_NAME, modControllers), service provider can also be used in the same way as service instance to declare route controllers in `config` block:

```
...
controller: ctrlFactoryProvider.get('ListController')
```

Because `$controller` doesn't expose the list of registered controllers, try-catching it comes to mind as automatic solution, and it is the last thing the one may want to do: besides it is a hack, it just suppresses possible exceptions and damages testability.

Comment: I like this approach.  I will definitely try this and let you know. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: One more thing. I am also using ng-router with ng-view. Will this approach go with that. My url pattarn are like /list for list controler or / edit/:id for edit controller.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in original question and it is an important detail because it changes everything. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

In .config you can only use providers (e.g. $routeProvider).

In .run you can only use instances of services (e.g. $route).

> $controller is of type service which can not be used in .config.

For more detail on this read [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

The detailed discussion on Stack Overflow at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828287/what-things-can-be-injected-into-others-in-angular-js) thread shows what can be injected into others.

Comment: Then is it possible to check a controller is exists or not in .config?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734565/how-to-check-if-an-angularjs-controller-has-been-defined

Comment: Already checked that post and also mentation in the question. There is a answer (posted by @trekforever) which suggest to update angular code. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can not inject `$controller` into config

Although you can use the following service to check if your controller is defined.

```
angular.service('ControllerChecker', ['$controller', function($controller) {
  return {
    exists: function(controllerName) {
      if(typeof window[controllerName] == 'function') {
        return true;
      }
      try {
        $controller(controllerName);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return !(error instanceof TypeError);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Now you can inject `ControllerChecker` and call its `exists(CtrlName)` function to check whether your controller is defined or not.

Comment: If I use $controller as dependency injection, it is giving

Unknown provider: $controller

Comment: I have already seen that post before posting this question. I am also not able to access that service,  so I tried to access $controller directlly.

Comment: Same way I can not access the ControllerChecker service also. :)

Comment: Do not inject this service in config. Instead inject it in your root controller.